# PIG - Defining the delimiter used for a bag after a GROUP function

Tags: apache-pig

In Pig, I'm loading and grouping two files. I end up with a something like this:

```
A = LOAD 'File1' Using PigStorage('\t');
B = LOAD 'File2' Using PigStorage('\t');
C = COGROUP A BY $0, B BY $0;
STORE C INTO 'Output' USING PigStorage('\t');
```

Output:

```
123 {(123,XYZ,456)} {(123,QRS,889,QWER)}
```

Where the first field is the group key, the first bag is from File1, and the next bag is from File2. These three sections are delimited from each other using whatever I identified in the PigStorage('\t') clause.

Question: How do I force Pig to delimit the bags by something other than a comma? In my real data, there are commas present and so I need to delimit by tabs instead.

Desired output:

```
123 {(123\tXYZ\t456)} {(123\tQRS\t889\tQWER)}
```

Comment: Was my answer useful? If so, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an open issue (as of June 2013) in Pig. See the corresponding [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1271) for more details. Until the issue is fixed, you can change your input data.